# Kivy installation and UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: pip, kivy, virtualenv

I'm trying to instal Kivy on my Windows 10 Polish language.
Python 3.8
PIP 19.3.1

When i get to step:

```
python -m virtualenv kivy_venv
```

im getting error:

```
C:\Users\Paweł>python -m virtualenv kivy_venv
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python\\Python38-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\Paweł\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 939, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 42: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2634, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 860, in main
    create_environment(
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1179, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1023, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1116, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 941, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(fs_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 42: invalid start byte
```

I couldn't find solution to this version of python or pip that's why i ask for help.
If you have any ideas please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find solution 
Control panel regional settings Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support must be tick.
[Use Unicode UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv0tU.png)